# Diferença entre salvar o form direto e criar instância do model

Tags: django, formulário, django-2.2

Venho tendo alguns problemas quando vou inserir ou modificar algum valor que não foi passado para o usuário no form e depois salvá-lo.

Por exemplo eu tenho um model de Local :

```
models.py

class Local(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    descricao = models.TextField()
    avaliado = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

No form contém :

```
forms.py

class FormLocal(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Local
        fields = ['nome', 'descricao']
```

E na view quando faço assim da errado:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        local = FormLocal(request.POST)

        if local.is_valid():
            local.save(commit=False)    
            local.avaliado = True 
            local.save()
            return redirect("listar_local")
```

Apresenta o seguinte erro :

```
IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed
```

Mas quando faço assim  da certo:

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
        local = FormLocal(request.POST)

        if local.is_valid():
            local.save(commit=False)    
            loc = Local(nome=local.cleaned_data.get('nome'),
                descricao = local.cleaned_data.get('descricao'),
                avaliado=True)
            loc.save()
            return redirect("listar_local")
```

Por que não consigo mudar o valor e salvar no banco mas quando eu crio a instância do model e salvo da certo ?

Isso ainda está um pouco confuso para mim: quando devo criar a instância do model e quando devo salvar com o form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi o seu ModelForm não contempla o campo avaliado. E você está tentando altera-lo manualmente, daí o erro.

O correto seria isso:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    local = FormLocal(request.POST)

    if local.is_valid():
        local_novo = local.save(commit=False)    
        local_novo.avaliado = True 
        local_novo.save()
        return redirect("listar_local")
```